# unwanted horizontal spacing between my ImageViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to place four ImageViews in a 2x2 grid fashion, and I tried everything that I know from a tableLayout to a relativeLayout and finally a nested Layout as the following

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/top">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    />



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/top"
    android:id="@+id/btm">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"

    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
    /></LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/changepic"
    android:id="@+id/button"

    android:layout_below="@id/btm"/>
```

but no matter what I do, I always get this "unwanted" horizontal spacing between ImageViews in same row, which is surprisingly absent between ImageViews verticaly, as the pic. 
[Picture Here](http://postimg.org/image/3rjaf22o9/)
what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of the linear layout altogether-  you don't need it, and adding extra views has bad performance issues on android.  Instead make the second image android:layout_toRightOf the left one.  That should also kill the space.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    />



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    />
...
```

In addition-  are you sure your width is correct?  You have it as a pair of 150dpx150dp images.  Those images are not square.  You may not be that wide, so the extra space is because the image only fills part of that 150dp.  You probably want wrap_content for width.

Comment: Look like he adjusting view bounds may help as well.

Comment: Hi Gabe, like I said I tried the relative Layout using both the toRightOf and Below attribute but I got the same result. I'm curious as to why these spaces disappear vertically but appear horizontally??

Comment: the weirdest thing just happened, I changed my Layout back to RelativeLayout and changed width to wrap_content and this is what I got

Comment: it did work for me after two things: 1- change width to wrap_content 2-tilt screen

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think I have a problem with my custom pictures, as if I tried the ic_launcher it works...?

Comment: @RaedTabani if you could get with ic_launcher means that there is no problem with your layout. make sure that your custom raw images has no margin

Comment: the image has no margin as it worked by tilting the screen and changing the width and height to wrap_content instead of fixed dp